# vba more realistic random number generator

Tags: vba, random

I know I can use a quasi-random number generation function/variable called Rnd. However, I've noticed that whenever I used Rnd in my userform, this sequence of numbers always show up:

first iteration: 0.705547511577606
second iteration: 0.533424019813538
...

As a result, b/c the sequence of numbers showing up are the same every time when I relaunch the userform, it doesn't feel random. Are there other functions in the VBA function set that would make it feel more random? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding a single call to `Randomize Timer` before you do any calls to `Rnd`.  This will seed the random number generator using the time of day.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a lot about VB but I think you need to *seed* your number generator. I think `Randomize` does it for VB.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the seed based on the time of day... insert something like this at the top of your vba code:

```
For i = 0 To (CInt(Format(Time, "ms"))) 'minutes and seconds turned to integer
        test_random = Rnd()
    Next
```